# Expected number of flips vs probability in a Markov Chain

Tags: probability, probability-theory, markov-chains, markov-process, transition-matrix

The problem is the following: 
(a) We keep flipping coins until we see the sequence HTHH. Find the expected number
of flips. 
(b) Alice and Bob play the following game. They keep flipping coins until either the
sequence HHTH or HTHH occurs. Alice wins if the sequence HHTH occurs first, and
Bob wins if the sequence HTHH occurs first. Find the probability that Alice wins. 
For part (a) I set a transition matrix with states {0, 1, 2, 3, 4} corresponding to the "progress" made in achieving the sequence HTHH. Going from 0 to 0 means getting a Tails, going from 0 to 1 means getting Heads, from 1 to 1 means getting Heads again, from 1 to 2 means getting Tails (after getting Heads), going from 2 to 0 is getting Tails (after getting Tails) and so on.

$\begin{bmatrix} 0.5 & 0.5 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 0.5 & 0.5 & 0 & 0 \\ 0.5 & 0 & 0 & 0.5 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 0.5 & 0 & 0.5 \\ 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 \end{bmatrix}$

The expected number of tosses would be first entry of the solution to $\overrightarrow{v}=R\overrightarrow{v}+\begin{pmatrix} 1 \\ 1 \\ 1 \\ 1 \end{pmatrix}$ if I'm not mistaken, which is 18. 
Now for part (b) I don't know how to set up the matrices for Alice and Bob (if even that is the correct approach). I would greatly appreciate any advice on how to proceed, thank you!

Comment: The problem in the literature is called "Penney's Game"

Comment: For part (b) symmetry gives each p=0.5, since both sequences have the same probability.

Comment: That makes sense! Is there a way to show this using the transition matrices or other properties?

Comment: There is no such symmetry argument. There would be if you did 3 flips, then reset if no one wins, etc., but there is not; you consider all the substrings. This means one player can definitely have an advantage. What's interesting to me is that the player who has the advantage is not necessarily the one who has the lower expected number of flips before their sequence is seen.

Comment: (Where I said 3 I should have said 4.)

Comment: @herbsteinberg very wrong.  That you suggested it shows that you have never seen Penney's game before.  It is well known that problems like this defy naive intuition.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can also solve part (b) using a Markov chain, having the $8$ states described in the table below.  The first column of the table is an index for each state, the second and third are the number of steps which Alice and Bob will have taken towards their targets in the give state, and the third and fourth are the indices of next states when heads or tails is tossed in the given state.  The final column lists all the preceding sequences of tosses of lengths $0$ to $4$ that would lead up to the given state, with $\ \lambda\ $ denoting the empty sequence.

\begin{array}{ccccl}
\text{State}&\text{Alice}&\text{Bob}&\text{Next}_H&\text{Next}_T&\text{Preceding sequences}\\
1&2&1&1&2&HH,THH,HHH,TTHH,THHH,HHHH\\
2&3&2&3&8&HHT,HHHT,THHT\\
3&4&2&3&3&HHTH\\
4&2&4&4&4&HTHH\\
5&1&2&7&8&HT,THT,TTHT,HTHT\\
6&1&1&1&5&H,TH,TTH,TTTH,HTTH\\
7&1&3&4&5&HTH,THTH\\
8&0&0&6&8&\lambda,T,TT,HTT,TTT,HHTT,TTTT,HTTT,THTT
\end{array}
States $3$ and $4$ are absorbing states in which Alice or Bob, respectively, have won the game.  The transition matrix is
$$
P=\pmatrix{0.5&0.5&0&0&0&0&0&0\\
0&0&0.5&0&0&0&0&0.5\\
0&0&1&0&0&0&0&0\\
0&0&0&1&0&0&0&0\\
0&0&0&0&0&0&0.5&0.5\\
0.5&0&0&0&0.5&0&0&0\\
0&0&0&0.5&0.5&0&0&0\\
0&0&0&0&0&0.5&0&0.5}
$$
The probability that Alice wins is the probability that the chain ends up in state $3$.  If you let $\ a_k\ $ be the probability that Alice wins, given that the current state is $\ k\ $, then obviously $\ a_3=1\ $, $\ a_4=0\ $, and
$$
a_k=\sum_{j=1}^8p_{kj}a_j\  ,
$$
where $\ p_{kj}\ $ is the entry in the $\ k^\text{th}\ $ row and $\ j^\text{th}\ $ column of $\ P\ $. The third and fourth of these equations are the tautologies $\ 1=1\ $ and $\ 0=0\ $, respectively, and the rest may be written as
$$
\pmatrix{a_1\\a_2\\a_5\\a_6\\a_7\\a_8}=\pmatrix{0.5&0.5&0&0&0&0\\
0&0&0&0&0&0.5\\
0&0&0&0&0.5&0.5\\
0.5&0&0.5&0&0&0\\
0&0&0.5&0&0&0\\
0&0&0&0.5&0&0.5}\pmatrix{a_1\\a_2\\a_5\\a_6\\a_7\\a_8}+\pmatrix{0\\0.5\\0\\0\\0\\0}
$$
The solution of these equation is
$$
\pmatrix{a_1\\a_2\\a_5\\a_6\\a_7\\a_8}=\pmatrix{\frac{4}{5}\\\frac{4}{5}\\\frac{2}{5}\\\frac{4}{5}\\\frac{3}{5}\\\frac{1}{5}\\\frac{3}{5}}\ .
$$
The probability you want is the probability, $a_8=\frac{3}{5}\ $, that Alice wins given that the Markov chain is in state $8$, because that is the state it will be in when the game starts, which thus confirms the results of [true blue anil's simulation](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4433281/expected-number-of-flips-vs-probability-in-a-markov-chain/4433548#4433548).

Answer (score 0):

For part **(a)**, checking by a different method, I get the same result for the expected number of flips.
Renaming the states $\;0,1,2,3\;$ as $\;a,b,c,d$
the equations for $HTHH$ would be

$\displaylines{a = 1 +0.5b+0.5a\\b=1+0.5c+0.5b\\c=1+0.5d+0.5a\\d=1+0.5c}$

which yields $ a=18$

For part **(b)**, I don't see how there is symmetry.
I don't know exactly how to compute the probability,
so I ran it on an [online simulator](https://flown.io/penneys-game/) which gives $HTHH$ a win probability of around $0.6$

Comment: The main mistake in your part a is in the equation for d, i.e. where the last three flips were HTH. In this case if you get T then your last four flips are HTHT, and in particular your last two flips were HT, so you go back to state 2 not state 0. You also forgot the +1 in the equation for c though I suspect given your answer being too high that you didn't do this in your numerics.

Comment: @Ian: Thanks for pointing out the typo/slip, amended. The main reason I went to the question was to point out that symmetry doesn't exist, and to give a figure for   part (b)

Answer (score 0):

In (a) the last equation in your system is wrong. You should have $\mathbf{v}_4=0$ (zero indexing as you did). But instead you defined it as $\mathbf{v}_4=\mathbf{v}_4+1$ which actually has no solution at all. Edit: this was me misreading OP by assuming $R$ was the same as $P$ when actually $R$ is the top left $4 \times 4$ block of $P$. OP's part a is actually correct.

There is a solution to (b) using a similar renewal theory setup to what you did. But I don't immediately see a way to avoid working with the entire state, i.e. a $16 \times 16$ transition matrix. So I will describe how to do it with a big matrix like this.

Suppose you have already flipped at least four coins (the first four flips will be handled separately at the end). Treat the most recent four flips as the state of the process. If you think in a binary encoding with the older flips to the left, the update is done as follows: discard the leftmost bit, then insert a random bit on the right. So the first 8 rows of the transition probability matrix describe these transitions:

$$0000 \to 0000,0001 \\
0001 \to 0010,0011 \\
0010 \to 0100,0101 \\
0011 \to 0110,0111 \\
0100 \to 1000,1001 \\
0101 \to 1010,1011 \\
0110 \to 1100,1101 \\
0111 \to 1110,1111$$

The remaining 8 rows are the same behave the same because the leftmost bit wasn't actually being used (so for programming you can just vertically concatenate two copies of this $8 \times 16$ matrix).

This gives you a transition matrix $P$ (row-stochastic). Define $L=P-I$. For ease of notation, say heads are 1s and convert to decimal (zero indexing again). Then you want to find the solution to $(L\mathbf{v})_j=0,j \neq 11,13,\mathbf{v}_{11}=1,\mathbf{v}_{13}=0$. The answer to your question is then $\mathbf{u} \mathbf{v}$ where $\mathbf{u}=(1/16,\dots,1/16)$ (a row vector).

Comment: I probably should mention that the matrix $R$ to which I refer in my question is the first 4 columns and 4 rows of the transition matrix. The reason why I'm adding the "only-ones-vector" is that for each state we have to count a coin toss. I also figured out how to set up a 7×7 transition matrix for part (b) and I got 0.6 for an answer, which is the probability true blue anil mentioned before. Thank you for the answer anyway!!

Comment: @LeonardoMattiazzi With it trimmed down then you have (a) right.

Comment: @LeonardoMattiazzi BTW 0.6 is the probability Bob wins, not the probability Alice wins. (true blue anil did get and state the right answer though.)

Comment: Oh that is true. I wonder why I got the probabilities switched.